# Import a large database - CPanel & MySQL & PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a database which has the size over 100 MB. It has the `.sql.gz` which means it is compressed. When I try to import it using PHPMyAdmin I get time out errors. I even tried partial imports ( *Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. (This might be good way to import large files, however it can break transactions.)* ) which does not work for me. Given that I'm using CPanel & PHPMyAdmin to get the job done.

How can import this database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [***BigDump***](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) for this

1. Adjust the database configuration and charset in this file
2. Remove the old tables on the target database if your dump doesn't contain "DROP TABLE"
3. Create the working directory (e.g. dump) on your web server
4. Upload bigdump.php and your dump files (.sql, .gz) via FTP to the working directory
5. Run the bigdump.php from your browser via URL like 
   http://www.yourdomain.com/dump/bigdump.php
6. BigDump can start the next import session automatically if you enable the JavaScript
7. Wait for the script to finish, do not close the browser window
8. IMPORTANT: Remove bigdump.php and your dump files from the web server

If Timeout errors still occure you may need to adjust the `$linepersession` setting in this file. [Read more](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/)

Answer (score 5):

Very Simple and Effective Technique to import large mysql databases.

1. **Using Command Line console**

you can access command line using putty for server and execute following command

```
mysql -u 'database_user' -p'database_password' database_name < sql_file_name_with_full_path
```

2. **Using Cron Job [if console is not available]**

add a cron job in cpanel with following command

```
mysql -u 'database_user' -p'database_password' database_name < sql_file_name_with_full_path
```

**Do not forget to delete cron job after importing database. Also delete sql file from server.**

for both techniques commands are same

Example

```
mysql -u 'test_user' -p'123456' test_db < /home1/test/public_html/db.sql
```

or if you do not have password

```
mysql -u 'test_user' test_db < /home1/test/public_html/db.sql
```

Comment: Thanks @Moritz I will take care next time.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion and experience with [hepsiawebhosting.com](http://hepsiawebhosting.com) server, it's better and faster to set those parameters under WHM settings called "Tweak setting". Under Tweak settings you can modify maximum upload and maximum post, and you can could, for example, change upload to 120 MiB and post to 125 MiB.

Also, in PHP settings under WHM, you can change the default socket and SQL time out. You need to increase those settings.

You can also unzip the database and try to upload it as a simple .sql file.

I hope this will help you.

---

why this is not published, what is missing here?